# Looping through thousands of records using node and firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, firebase

I've got in my Firebase data store around 10,000 records, each with some data attached to it eg.

```
productName: {
 price: 10.00,
 lastChecked: timestamp,
 url: 'http://product/url',
 imagePath: 'http://product/image/url'
}
```

I loop through each product, and with each product data it retrieves it then goes and performs other tasks.

I got it all working when I only had a few hundred records but now I've got thousands (with lots more to come), when I run the task it crashes du to CPU overload and the majority of the products don't perform their tasks.

I've read about loop blocking and tried timeouts in callbacks which I read in a few posts which improved a little, but haven't yet managed to prevent the server CPU to overload.

This is an example I've implemented from a another article.

```
        getProductData = function(product, callback){
            ref.child('products/'+product).once('value', function(snapshot) {
                    callback(snapshot.val(), product);
                });
            },

        queryProductData = function(product){
            getProductData(product, function (productData, productKey) {                    
                 setTimeout(scrapeProductDetails(product), 2000) //queue for next ping in the next predefined interval
            });
        },

        productLoop = function(productsList) {                
            for (var product in productsList)
            {
                setTimeout(queryProductData(product), 2000) //queue job. Every 2 seconds, query_host will be called.
            }
        }
```

This is running as a Node service and not a website so will be running in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning this bit:

```
for (var product in productsList)
{
    setTimeout(queryProductData(product), 2000)
}
```

2 things that aren't quite right here:

- By doing `setTimeout(queryProductData(product), 2000)` you're already running the function before the timer starts. Look into [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to solve this.
- The for loop goes over each product all at once and creates the timers, so every timer will start at the same moment. The result: 2 seconds after the for loop, all functions will run simultaneously. So you're essentially still doing everything at once but you're adding a 2 second delay.

What you probably want would be a construction like this:

```
index = 0
function nextProduct() {
    productName = productsList[index] // get current product from list

    // Do what you need with productName

    index++ // Next product
}

setInterval(nextProduct, 2000);
```

`nextProduct` will get the next product from the list every time it is called, and `setInterval` will call `nextProduct` repeatedly every 2 seconds.

*Caveat* with the above: if `nextProduct` takes more than 2 seconds to run synchronously, `index` may not be updated by the time the next function is called, so it is best to update `index` as soon as you've used it to get the product name, and not actually at the end like in my example.

Another solution would be to have `nextProduct` call itself when done, instead of using `setInterval`. However, when using recursive functions there are other issues (like stack size limits) that you would need to overcome so I would advise against it for your use case.

I hope my answer has helped you, if not feel free to comment and I'll take another look at it.